replace analog phone with VoIP door box over 2-wire Ethernet?
Large office buildings and warehouses use analog phones at remote access points beyond the reach limit of 2-pair Ethernet.  The newer 2-wire Ethernet has much greater reach and can provide PoE to the remote device, such as a VoIP door box.  Sounds like a good idea, but my searches don't turn up any such 2-wire VoIP device.  Are there alternative ways to replace an analog phone with a VoIP unit using the existing wiring (probably Cat3)?

I'm not aware of any single pair ethernet tech outside of automotive circles (why it was invented) - and even there it's a unicorn. There's plenty of long-reach-ethernet (that's really just VDSL) stuff around, but even that stuff is getting pretty old. Cisco tried to revive it some years ago (made a few rounds on YT) but doesn't appear to have gone anywhere. If you're over 100m, power will be an issue.

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

You are probably referring to 10BASE-T1L (clause 146) with DPI aka PoDL (annex 146B). It is intended for industrial use.
Whether your telephone cabling is suitable, especially with lengths of more than 100 m, is doubtful. Cat3-ish cabling won't work. You'd need to evaluate your cabling as described in 802.3 or at least test thoroughly.
Finding an IP phone with that kind of port built in is not likely, even media converters with or without PoE/PoDL conversion seem to be hard to find, if they exist at all.
On the other hand, VDSL converters with less demand on the cabling do exist (fine with Cat3, but needs testing as well) but without power delivery support.
All in all, you should seriously consider renewing the cabling. For long links, fiber is practically mandatory.

I found this: "...high-speed, long-distance Ethernet & PoE extenders that enable the transmission of Ethernet signals and PoE up to 300m through a single pair of twisted wires. They offer a cost-effective and time-saving solution for migrating existing analog systems to IP-based systems, ...utilizing existing UTP bundle cables or any single twisted pair cables. With the long-distance transmission feature, these devices easily overcome the 100-meter distance limitation and significantly reduce construction costs compared to fiber optic configurations."
